# MVC EditorTemplate or HtmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper, mvc-editor-templates

I'm creating a page to show a list of items, one of the properties is a picture.

Now I'm building the Create View. 
I will add the drag and drop functionality so user can add the picture easy. 
But I want to code something easy to reuse.

Looks like I could do it putting the code in an EditorTemplate or a HtmlHelper. But don't know which one should be the proper way.

For my point of view EditorTemplate looks easier to implement becasue is just create a view and easy to include the Jquery script. 
HtmlHelper need to create a function returning a IHtmlHelper so I have to create the html string using several functions I'm not familiar with (but I could learn).

Comment: If its a one off for this project, an `EditorTemplate` would be easier. If its something that you would want across multiple projects then a HtmlHelper can be compiled in to a separate dll which you can reference. In any case do not include scripts an `EditorTemplate` (they belong in the main view - and you would be including multiple copies of the script - one for each item!)

Comment: Thanks @StephenMuecke Sound good. But In case of creating the dll, how you say this dll need this script.js to work? I mean i can add the script in the main page, otherwise i know wouldn't work. Just wonder how i document or tag the dll?

Answer (score 0):

Editor Template and HTMLHelper both has its own use

HTMLHelper

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;

namespace Helpers
{
    public static class HTMLHelper
    {

        public static MvcHtmlString DeleteActionLink(this AjaxHelper helper, string linkText, string ActionName,
            object routeValues)
        {
            return helper.ActionLink(linkText, ActionName, routeValues, new AjaxOptions
            {
                Confirm = "Are you sure you want to delete this item?",
                HttpMethod = "DELETE",
                OnSuccess = "function() {window.location.reload();}",
                OnFailure = "function() {alert('Your alert.');}"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

add reference of Helper namespace in view and use  it reuse it

Editor Template

for nullable datetime model to parse its time field

```
 @model DateTime?
    @if (Model.HasValue)
    {
        @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:t}", Model), new { @class = "timefield" })
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.TextBox("", "", new { @class = "time" })
    }
```